# Is there a way navigate directly to a section using check box 'click' in an Orbeon form?

Tags: orbeon

Based on user click (check box) need to navigate to specific section in the form. Please advise.

Comment: By "navigate to a specific section of the form", do you mean "scroll down to that section, and maybe set the focus on the first field in that section"? And is the checkbox part of the form? -Alex

Comment: Did you manage to achieve what you were looking for? If not, would you have some feedback with regards to my previous question? -Alex

Comment: Hi Alex, I managed with other options available. Thanks and need one more help. Can we make Mail recipient based on condition like if $email1= '' then $email2

Comment: Good, I'm glad you found a solution. For the email, you can use a Hidden Field, have its value calculated the way you suggest, and mark that field as the one to use the Email recipient; would this work in your case?